# Installation stops at "downloading file 159 of 159"

Tags: networking, system-installation, software-installation, 22.04, usb-installation

I try to install Ubuntu on my laptop asus, but when the download starts it pauses at "Downloading file 159 of 159" and there is no way to advance, I don't know what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the Ubuntu installing from downloading software by unchecking the Other options of *Download updates while installing Ubuntu* and *Install third-party software* at the *Updates and other software* screen.

[image]

This type of error can also occur when there are too many bad sectors on the hard drive. The Ubuntu installer will stop somewhere in the middle of the installation process until you replace the hard drive. This is easy to check if you have a replacement hard drive handy. Pull out the existing hard drive and try installing Ubuntu again on a different hard drive.

Comment: I just left the minimum install checkbox checked, and suddenly it worked and I managed to install it, but I still think the hard drive is a bit worn out, Thank you very much karel.